# Store remotely located XML file in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, importdata

I have succesfully loaded a copy of an xml file, which I stored in the same location of the SQL Server, into a SQL table using the following commands:

```
DECLARE @XML XML

SELECT @XML = X FROM OPENROWSET(BULK *path*, SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLData(X)
```

However, the original location of this xml file is on another server and SQL does not accept the path of the original location. Is there a way to directly pull the xml file into SQL from the original remote location?

Comment: What error do you get, and what does the path look like (not the real path values, just give us an example of what it looks like).

Comment: @RBarryYoung I get the following error with the path as stated in the error: "Cannot bulk load because the file "Q:\ folders \ file.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)." 
The path that does work is stored in a path starting with "E:\"

Comment: Is `Q:` a mapped drive? There's no restriction using remote file paths, UNC paths will work  with bulkload just fine. Check your spelling, spaces, permissions.

Comment: If you get the same error for the UNC path, does the service account which SQL Server is running under have access to that path? Don't forget, file access is very often run under the account that SQL Server is running under, *not* the credentials of the user who runs the query.

Comment: To extend the point @Larnu makes, drive mappings are also account specific in Windows.  You may have a Q: drive mapped to a remote path while logged on with your account, but the account the SQL Server instance runs as might (probably) doesn't.  This is why you should always use UNC paths (\\server\share\...) instead of drive letter mappings when accessing remote shares programatically.

Comment: @Larnu Using a UNC path indeed led to an access issue, however this is luckily solved by IT and things are working correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @squillman Thanks a lot for your valuable tip, will keep it in mind!